# position: absolute inside FlatList view child not overlay

Tags: react-native, position, absolute, flatlist

I have a FlatList with N childs, i want position a view with `absolute`, each children has a view who can be visible or not, I'm using `position: absolute` and `z-index: 20` in the view styles but didn't work, my view with position absolute is behind the children (the red container in the image)

Code example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-flatlist-example-forked-kchk5u?file=/src/App.js
The purple square in the image below should be in front of all red rectangles

[image]

Comment: Luiz, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you want a purple square in front of the entire flatlist container. Your approach of `{index === 1 && (` it's wrong, because position absolute means it's absolute just to the item, not the entire flatlist.

What you should do instead, is to mount the square at the same level with flatlist and position it over the flatlist, not inside it.

Something like this:

```
<ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <View
    style={{
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      backgroundColor: "red",
      position: "absolute",
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      zIndex: 1
    }}
  />
  <FlatList
    data={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
    renderItem={({ item }) => renderRestaurantInfo(item)}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.toString()}
    style={{
      flexGrow: 5,
      backgroundColor: "#ccc"
    }}
  />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: The ```{index === 1 && (``` is only to emulate the fact "view who can be visible or not", the objective is create something likes this: https://br.atsit.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/como-desativar-mostrar-mais-opcoes-no-menu-de-contexto-do-botao-direito-no-windows-11.png

A suspend list "more options" that can be visible when I click in three points. So, I not can put the purple view out of the flasList child

Comment: Each FlatList child has a purple view that in this example emulate a suspend list, when i click in three points in a child, the correspondent view is showing

Comment: I'm facing the same situation lol